# Web.config Redirect to new site, with and without params

Tags: redirect, iis, parameters, localhost, web-config

We have pulled out some code of our monolith, and build a separate application (With it's own url) instead. We need to be able to redirect links hitting the old monolith application new application.

Old url: https://OldApp.domain.com/OldAppContoller/123
New url: https://NewApp.domain.com/NewAppController/123
So when users go to the old url either with, or without the 123 id it should redirect to the new app.

Also if I'm running the Old application locally I need it to redirect direct it to our test environment "t-" like this:
Old url: https://localhost:7777/OldAppContoller/123
New url: https://t-NewApp.domain.com/NewAppController/123

And lastly I need to grab the environment prefix t,m,p to redirect to the correct environment.

I've been messing around with the web.config, but haven't found a working solution yet.
Here is what I've got:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="NewApp Localhost with Param" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*localhost.*OldAppContoller\/([0-9]*)"/>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://t-NewApp.domain.com/NewAppController/{r:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="NewApp Localhost without Param" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*localhost.*OldAppContoller"/>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://t-NewApp.domain.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="NewApp with Param" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*OldApp-([a-z]).*OldAppContoller\/([0-9]*)"/>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{r:1}-NewApp.domain.com/NewAppController/{r:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="NewApp without Param" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*OldApp-([a-z]).*OldAppContoller"/>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{r:1}-NewApp.domain.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm not sure if this is to be done with one rule, or multiple rules as my example above.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Make sure common mistakes are avoided https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 and then you are good to go.

Comment: You can try to use failed request tracking to see detailed request information, if it still doesn't solve the problem, please give an example of your problem, i will make demo for you.

Comment: I would recommend to add the redirect from localhost to test in the `web.config` file and then override this with the rule from oldapp to newapp in the `web.release.config` file. It's a bit hard to know exactly what is wrong with your rules. Maybe try one at the time. And try matching everything and specifying conditions like shown on the examples here: https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/#redirect-www-to-non-www

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I've been reading your links, and stilling messing around with it.  I guess another question could be, is this the right place to fix my redirect problem. I have a working solution sitting in the old Controler, that redirects to the new application. I just find it a more clean  cut to be able to delete that controller in the code cleanup process.

Comment: I didn't find a final solution for this. I reverted back to handle the redirection in the oldController. and removed my attemptes at handling it in the web.config. Thanks for your time and comments.

Comment: You can try open a case via : https://support.microsoft.com.